# C++: Does the terms element and value mean the same thing?

Tags: c++, c++11

Many times I see the term **value** and **element** being used in describing C++ functions and data structures.

Does these terms mean the same thing, or is **element** some abstract concept of a **value**?

Especially, http://www.cplusplus.com use both of these terms.

Thanks.

Comment: "Especially, http://www.cplusplus.com use both of these terms." – Especially, http://www.cplusplus.com is a big pile of smelly bullshit. Avoid that site like the plague. They are not authoritative reference on C++ by any means, and they **often** use confusing or downright wrong terminology.

Comment: I'd recommend http://en.cppreference.com/ rather.

Comment: this is a good question as it has implications for the interpretation of the standard. it's wrong to downvote it.

Comment: Although I have written an answer, it would help with a couple of quotes from the site, illustrating how these words are used - my answer is certainly describing the conceptual difference between value and element - but there may be other subtle differences.

Answer (score 5):

To me, those terms are not interchangeable, but can sometimes represent similar things.

Take for example:

```
 std::vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 42 };
```

This vector has 3 elements. Each element has a value, the value of the third element is 42. But the vector also contains three values [note the difference between "contains", not "has"].

In my vocabulary, a value is "the content just this momemnt".

If I do:

```
 v[2] += 6;
```

then the third element is still the same third element as it was before, but its value is now `48`, when it was `42` earlier. So, the element stays the same, the value changes.

Of course, a "value" of an element can be a pointer (`std::vector<int*>`), which then ALSO points at a value [or at `NULL` which doesn't have any value]. References also have a referant and a value in the referant.

Answer (score 2):

The term 'element' appears something like 1100 times in the standard text, and seems to be used for a wide variety of concepts, depending on the context of the text.

more formally in the standard library, the type `element_type` refers to the type yielded by dereferencing a pointer-like object (shared_ptr, unique_ptr, std::pointer_traits<> etc).

e.g:

```
using ptr_type = std::shared_ptr<int>;
using pointee_type = ptr_type::element_type;
static_assert(std::is_same<pointee_type, int>::value, "");
```

The type `value_type` refers to the values stored in a container.

Note that the `value_type` of a map is a `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`

and in a set, `value_type` is the same type as `key_type`.